# single class classifier using Gaussian Mixture Model

Tags: matlab, voice-recognition, mfcc

I am working on speaker identification project in matlab which my goal is to check whether a test speaker is my target speaker or not.
I used mfcc and lpcc and pitch as my features in this project and I used libsvm for single class classifier to train my model but my model accuracy even when I test it on my train data is quite low.
I use pre-implement mfcc and lpcc function which I am sure of correctness of this two features so I thought this might be a problem with classifier so I decide to use Gaussian Mixture Model as my classifier in this project however how can use Gaussian Mixture Model for single class classification?

Comment: Time to learn some theory. Identification is not a single class problem. You have two possible outcomes - speaker is the same or speaker is different. This is a two class problem.

Comment: @ Nikolay Shmyrev so should I have to have two train dataset, target voices and other people voices?

Comment: Exactly! Overall, you'd better start with modern dnn-based speakerid system instead of doing basic things. Like with https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/tree/master/egs/sre16